# How to find port on windows (using pid or processes name)

Tags: powershell, batch-file

How to find port on windows (using pid or processes name)

I know the PID, but I need the port on which the processes are running

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following CMD command (Open it as administrator)

```
 netstat -aon | findstr PID
```

There more different ways to find process port available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows).

Comment: Thanks for response!!!
specifically want only the port of a processes, I know the name and PID of that processes, how to find the port

Comment: You can use this command to find a port used by process:
`netstat -aon | findstr PID`

Updated initial comment

Comment: Thank you so much...... **TCP    0.0.0.0:81             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5424**          I am getting this kind of result which is ok, but I want that port only, what to do for it

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to the question that [Nikita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75189590/45375) links to - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199/45375 - can be adapted to your needs with the following PowerShell command (assumes that the PID of interest is stored in `$yourPid`):

```bash
(Get-NetTCPConnection | Where-Object OwningProcess -eq $yourPid).LocalPort |
  Select-Object -Unique
```

Note that even weeding out duplicates can result in *multiple* ports getting returned.

See also:

- [`Get-NetTCPConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection)